# Issue With tab-host android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Guys i am facing a different problem with Tab-host,I will explain with steps clearly.

1.I am displaying the tab-host with 6 tabs.

2.On  Click of the sixth tab, i am displaying the popup, which consists of Buttons.Until here every thing is working fine to me.

3.When button is clicked in popup. I need to display the another activity,but tab-host should be at bottom for every screen?

for displaying the tab-host&popup i am using the following code.

private void setuptabs() {

```
    // Adding the tabs to TabHost.
    addTab("Balances", R.drawable.tab_search, BalancesActivity.class);
    addTab("Orders", R.drawable.tab_search, OrdersActivity.class);
    addTab("positions", R.drawable.tab_search, PositionsActivity.class);
    addTab("Trade", R.drawable.tab_search, TradeActivity.class);
    addTab("WatchList", R.drawable.tab_search, WatchlistActivity.class);
    addTab("Chains", R.drawable.tab_search, ChainsActivity.class);
    addTab("More", R.drawable.tab_search, MoreActivity.class);



    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(6).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            QuickActionView qa = QuickActionView.Builder(v);

            // set the adapter
            qa.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

            // set the number of columns ( setting -1 for auto )
            qa.setNumColumns(1);
            qa.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected item: " + which,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    switch (which) {
                    case 0:

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            // finally show the view
            qa.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}



private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    intent = new Intent(this, c);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    // txtTitle will set the title in TabHost.
    txtTitle = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.txtTitles);
    txtTitle.setText(labelId);
    // imgTab will set the image in TabHost.
    imgTab = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.imgTab);
    imgTab.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(7).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    System.out.println("Checking tabhost value::>"+tabHost.getChildCount());


}
```

Please guys,How i can achieve this....

Comment: Whats your problem exactly? Problem is "tab-host should be at bottom for every screen" only?

Comment: yes tabhost should be at bottom for every screen..

Answer (score 0):

It is something like you are calling first activity from tab click. that first activity have popup window. Now with click on button of popup window you are calling the Second Activity right ???
Is it right then you have to have that all activity in that perticular tab. and for that follow this link: [THIS LINK](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Comment: sry this i have did in my code...My requirement is not this,on click of tabwidget i will display popup,which consists of buttons.when i will click the button ,i need to go new activity but tabhost should be remain same....

Comment: sry....I will explain u more clearly,Think First activity is of tabhost.it consists of 6 tabs,when i clicked on sixth tab, i will display the popwindow. which consists of buttons, when i clicked first button in popup window new activity should be started..by tabhost should remain same.on click of sixth button i am using following code..

Comment: Can u check the code following line..QuickActionView qa = QuickActionView.Builder(v); in my question plz..

Answer (score 0):

For my application i'm already having this problem. In my application i've listview contains some items. When, i press anyone of the item will be displayed with detailed view to an another layout. And, i've use this code to do that -

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview12);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String newsid = hashMap.get("id");
                int integerid = Integer.parseInt(newsid);
                description(integerid);

                //Get the new Activity to tab.
                Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), detailedview.class);
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                parentActivity.startChildActivity("detailedview", previewMessage);
            }
        });
```

I just follow these code and  done my issues through out this [Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html). It provides `Parent` & `Child` method. Its very useful for me. And, it'll very useful to you also. Just try it out...! Hope this helps you.. :-)